# Two colors of text in Android progress dialog message

Tags: android, textview, progressdialog

I have a progress dialog and I want to display text message like below

1. Downloading
2. Decompressing

Can I display "1. Downloading" in green and "2. Decompressing" red. where as my code is

```
mProgressDialog.setMessage("1. Downloading \n 2. Decompressing");
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at this code.

```
final SpannableStringBuilder sb = new SpannableStringBuilder("your text here");
   final ForegroundColorSpan fcs = new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.rgb(158, 158, 158)); 

   // Span to set text color to some RGB value
   final StyleSpan bss = new StyleSpan(android.graphics.Typeface.BOLD); 

   // Span to make text bold
   sb.setSpan(fcs, 0, 4, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE); 

   // Set the text color for first 4 characters
   sb.setSpan(bss, 0, 4, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE); 

   // make them also bold
   yourTextView.setText(sb);
```

Answer (score 4):

I think you can use HTML in set message - it works for Alert and text views - I havent tried for progress dialog but try it.To give you an idea here's some code - just modify it to suit your requirements

Basically

In your strings.xml

```
 <string name="downloading"><![CDATA[<font color="green">1.Downloading</font><br/>]]></string>
 <string name="decompressing"><![CDATA[<font color="red">2.Decompressing</font><br/>]]></string>
```

And call

```
mProgressDialog.setMessage(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.downloading))+""+ Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.decompressing)));
```

Comment: not working, it is showing int value of R.string.downloading etc instead of colored text

Comment: Yikes let me check - yeah it needs a getstring function